# How to iterate over the following structure in Meteor Spacebars?

Tags: loops, meteor, underscore.js

I'm trying to group a collection by date in Meteor using Underscore's _.groupBy function.

Here is a sample of the code that outputs:

```
"Mon Dec 07 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)":[
  {
     "_id":"q9TMi9ZyoRjmddzfY",
     "title":"New event",
     "type":"collectif",
     "product":"passeport",
     "date":"2015-12-07T00:00:00.000Z",
     "start":"2015-12-07T08:00:00.000Z",
     "end":"2015-12-07T09:00:00.000Z",
     "teachers":[

     ],
     "clients":[
        {
           "clientId":"M4DDCGWGMzX7bJRHa",
           "manual":"true"
        }
     ],
     "clientLimit":99
  }
 ],
 "Tue Dec 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)":[
  {
     "_id":"Jbchuc58zWDyEqnQZ",
     "title":"New event",
     "type":"collectif",
     "product":"passeport",
     "date":"2015-12-08T00:00:00.000Z",
     "start":"2015-12-08T08:30:00.000Z",
     "end":"2015-12-08T09:30:00.000Z",
     "teachers":[

     ],
     "clients":[

     ],
     "clientLimit":15
  },
  {
     "_id":"EsqygwCCPucGhx9nP",
     "title":"New event",
     "type":"collectif",
     "product":"passeport",
     "date":"2015-12-08T00:00:00.000Z",
     "start":"2015-12-08T09:30:00.000Z",
     "end":"2015-12-08T10:30:00.000Z",
     "teachers":[
        "eLExMRh3TT5eYWpki",
        "wxFjH39M9kuBTv4zN"
     ],
     "clients":[

     ],
     "clientLimit":10
  }
]
}
```

The problem is, I'm not really sure how I can output these in the front-end. Do I have to somehow convert it to normal arrays or a cursor? Or is there perhaps another way of grouping a collection by date headings?

I'm looking to output something like the following:

```
Saturday 21st September
- Item 1
- Item 2

Tuesday 24th September
- Item 3
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

loops.html

```
{{#each arrayify data}}
  {{name}} <br>
  <ul>
    {{#each value}}
        <li>ClientLimit: {{this.clientLimit}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

loops.js

```
Template.registerHelper('arrayify',function(obj){
    result = [];
    for (var key in obj) result.push({name:key,value:obj[key]});
    return result;
  });

Template.hello.helpers({

data: function() {
      return {
        "Mon Dec 07 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)":[
          {
            "_id":"q9TMi9ZyoRjmddzfY",
            "title":"New event",
            "type":"collectif",
            "product":"passeport",
            "date":"2015-12-07T00:00:00.000Z",
            "start":"2015-12-07T08:00:00.000Z",
            "end":"2015-12-07T09:00:00.000Z",
            "teachers":[

            ],
            "clients":[
              {
                "clientId":"M4DDCGWGMzX7bJRHa",
                "manual":"true"
              }
            ],
            "clientLimit":99
          }
        ],
        "Tue Dec 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)":[
          {
            "_id":"Jbchuc58zWDyEqnQZ",
            "title":"New event",
            "type":"collectif",
            "product":"passeport",
            "date":"2015-12-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "start":"2015-12-08T08:30:00.000Z",
            "end":"2015-12-08T09:30:00.000Z",
            "teachers":[

            ],
            "clients":[

            ],
            "clientLimit":15
          },
          {
            "_id":"EsqygwCCPucGhx9nP",
            "title":"New event",
            "type":"collectif",
            "product":"passeport",
            "date":"2015-12-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "start":"2015-12-08T09:30:00.000Z",
            "end":"2015-12-08T10:30:00.000Z",
            "teachers":[
              "eLExMRh3TT5eYWpki",
              "wxFjH39M9kuBTv4zN"
            ],
            "clients":[

            ],
            "clientLimit":10
          }
        ]
      }
});
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks so much that works perfectly, just trying to figure out what's going on!